# Deletion of Inline Record is executed but a warning appears: Attempt to modify record without permission or non-existing page

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

On saving a record in Backend I'm using the TCEmainHook processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray. I'm creating, changing and deleting Inline Records there according to other fields in this records. Everything works as aspected, but there is still an Error/Warning on deletion of Inline Records, even the job is executed right. The Errors occur in TYPO3 7 and 8.

In Detail: I get the following Flash Message (in TYPO3 7 its only written in sys_log) for each Inline Record I deleted:

> Attempt to modify record 'foo bar' (tx_datednews_domain_model_newsrecurrence:527) without permission. Or non-existing page.

In TYPO3 8 I could follow the problem to the typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php Method: recordInfoWithPermissionCheck.
There is an Deleted Restriction added. When I remove that, everything is fine. That leads me to the idea, that the records are deleted already, therefore it can not found the records anymore. But I'm not deleting it twice.

But as I mentioned above, at the end the deletion of this Inline Records has been executed perfectly.

These might be the relevant code snippets:

The deletion/removing of the inline records is done with the following way. Switching these two lines didn't help. Using only one of these leads to either an fatal error when I reopen the news and didn't remove oldRec from the news record or its removed but not deleted. So I'm sure I need to do both steps.

```
$this->newsRecurrenceRepository->remove($oldRec);
$news->removeNewsRecurrence($oldRec);
```

TCA of tx_datednews_domain_model_newsrecurrence:

```
return [
'ctrl' => [
    'title'                    => 'LLL:EXT:dated_news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_datednews_domain_model_newsrecurrence',
    'label'                    => 'eventstart',
    'tstamp'                   => 'tstamp',
    'crdate'                   => 'crdate',
    'cruser_id'                => 'cruser_id',
    'default_sortby'           => 'eventstart',
    'versioningWS'             => true,
    'languageField'            => 'sys_language_uid',
    'transOrigPointerField'    => 'l10n_parent',
    'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
    'delete'                   => 'deleted',
    ...
```

TCA of Inline Element:

```
'newsrecurrence' => [
    'config'  => [
        'type'              => 'inline',
        'foreign_table'     => 'tx_datednews_domain_model_newsrecurrence',
        'MM'                => 'tx_datednews_news_newsrecurrence_mm',
        'foreign_field'     => 'parent_event', 
        'foreign_default_sortby'    => 'eventstart DESC',
        'maxitems'          => 9999,
        'appearance'        => [
            'collapseAll'                     => 1,
            'levelLinksPosition'              => 'top',
            'showSynchronizationLink'         => 1,
            'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
            'useSortable'                     => 0,
            'showAllLocalizationLink'         => 1,
            'enabledControls'                 => [
                'info'     => true,
                'new'      => false,
                'dragdrop' => true,
                'sort'     => false,
                'hide'     => true,
                'delete'   => false,
                'localize' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Defaul QuerySettings in newsRecurrenceRepository:

```
$this->defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
$this->defaultQuerySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields(true);
$this->defaultQuerySettings->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['hidden', 'deleted']);
$this->defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
```

It would be so great to understand why that Warning appears and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Your backend user has admin access? Or is it restricted?

Comment: Yes, the only user I have is an admin

Answer (score 1):

The solution is, to use the DataHandler Object which is available in the hook as $pObj.

So instead removing the record with the repository, it needs to be removed using the DataHandler. I replaced the line

```
$this->newsRecurrenceRepository->remove($oldRec);
```

with this piece of code:

```
$cmd = [];
$cmd['tx_datednews_domain_model_newsrecurrence'][$oldRec->getUid()]['delete'] = true;
$pObj->start([], $cmd);
$pObj->process_cmdmap();
```